# Setting both text and value to ComboBox items in WFA

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a web application in which I display a list of items (listItem). To each element, I assign its text and a value.

I can retrieve the value by using SelectedValue.

I am now building this web page as a WFA, and so far I am only able to assign the text to each comboBox items.

I would like to add a value to it (which would be an id from the database), so I can then use that value to efficiently update/delete etc.

How would you guys go about it?

Thanks

Comment: If you're porting a `Web` application to a `Windows` application, I strongly suggest WPF instead of winforms. winforms is a really old technology no one cares about anymore, while the preferred and default option to create .Net Windows applications (as per [Microsoft Official Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/companion-moc.aspx)) is currently WPF. the WPF paradigm is much closer to the Web paradigm than the traditional winforms approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties that you are used to are not present in Winforms, but since the `ComboBox` takes an object, you can make your own Custom Class with the Properties that you need. I have taken the MSDN Documentation on the [ListControl.DisplayMember Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) and modified it as an example.

What it does is create a custom class called `customComboBoxItem` with a `Text` and a `Value` Property, I then make a List and assign it as the `DataSource` of your `ComboBox` assigning the `Text` Property as the DisplayMember. See if this is workable for you.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<customComboBoxItem> customItem = new List<customComboBoxItem>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        customItem.Add(new customComboBoxItem("text1", "id1"));
        customItem.Add(new customComboBoxItem("text2", "id2"));
        customItem.Add(new customComboBoxItem("text3", "id3"));
        customItem.Add(new customComboBoxItem("text4", "id4"));
        comboBox1.DataSource = customItem;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show( ((customComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Text + " " 
                         + ((customComboBoxItem)comboBox1.SelectedItem).Value); 
    }
}

public class customComboBoxItem
{
    private string text;
    private string value;

    public customComboBoxItem(string strText, string strValue)
    {
        this.text = strText;
        this.value = strValue;

    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return value; }
    }

}
```